# Android: Finsky force-stops my application

Tags: android

I have an Android application which has a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Types-of-services).

The service also posts an *Ongoing notification* to the drawer, because

> Foreground services must display a Notification.

And it starts sticky:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

So Android shall keep this up, as

> if this service's process is killed while it is started, then leave it in the started state (...). Later the system will try to re-create the service.

However for some unknown reason, *Finsky* sometimes prevents this:

```
12-02 20:06:27.276 D/CCodecBuffers(23988): [c2.android.aac.decoder#777:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
12-02 20:06:27.393 I/Finsky  ( 4126): [2664] aliq.b(1): Attempting to stop application: net.MYAPP.android
12-02 20:06:27.396 I/ActivityManager( 1245): Force stopping net.MYAPP.android appid=10222 user=0: from pid 4126
12-02 20:06:27.397 I/ActivityManager( 1245): Killing 30598:net.MYAPP.android/u0a222 (adj 200): stop net.MYAPP.android
12-02 20:06:27.400 W/ActivityManager( 1245): Scheduling restart of crashed service net.MYAPP.android/.MYAPPService in 1000ms
12-02 20:06:27.403 I/ActivityManager( 1245):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{ace11d1 u0 net.MYAPP.android/.MYAPPService}
12-02 20:06:27.406 I/EdgeLightingManager( 1245): isCallingUserSupported : callingUserId=0, mUserId=0, isDualAppId=false
12-02 20:06:27.406 I/EdgeLightingManager( 1245): hideForNotification : packageName = net.MYAPP.android
12-02 20:06:27.406 I/EdgeLightingPolicyManager:NotificationGroup( 1245): remove : sbn : StatusBarNotification(pkg=net.MYAPP.android user=UserHandle{0} id=1337 tag=null key=0|net.MYAPP.android|1337|null|10222: Notification(channel=MYAPP_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x272 color=0x00000000 groupKey=MYAPP_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x8 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
12-02 20:06:27.406 I/EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup( 1245): group notification count : 1
12-02 20:06:27.406 I/EdgeLightingManager( 1245): hideForNotification : isInteractive is true
12-02 20:06:27.406 W/Finsky  ( 4126): [2664] alqs.a(41): Unwanted app (MUwS) without is_muws flag was returned with verdict POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED on autoscan: net.MYAPP.android
12-02 20:06:27.410 D/SamsungAlarmManager( 1245): Remove alarm for next reason : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED : package: net.MYAPP.android
```

My application is not uploaded into the store, it's in devel-phase yet.

What kind of application is *Finsky* actually?

It seems Finsky just thinks it is unwanted because `ActivityManager` is scheduling a restart of my crashed service. And my service is crashed because `Finksy` is attempting to stop application, and `ActivityManager` forces stopping due to this.

I believe the root cause shall be identified, ie: **Why is Finsky attempting to stop my application in the first place?**

Comment: I have a similar problem with this `Finsky`. Have you found out meanwhile how to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like I could trigger the same unwanted behavior by manually scanning with _Play Protect_. When I start this scan, my app crashes. So I turned _Play Protect_ off completely. However, it is really disappointing that the user is not notified about such events.

Comment: Hi, yes I did that also, it is really sad that android considers your dev application as 'unwanted'.

Comment: Well, that alone would not be that sad, actually, if the user was even given the opportunity to put the app to an exception list.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue where the application was being force stopped everyday at the same time. In the device log (retrieved by shell into the device and then logcat), there was a log that said 'Finsky  : [414] afha.j(1): Attempting to stop application'
**I had to go to the Play Store -> Play Protect -> Scan apps with Play Protect and turn this setting off.** This fixed the issue and my application is no longer being force stopped.
Apparently Google Play Store thinks of my application as an unwanted app and force stops it.